# Powershell Cryptographic Object without file input

Tags: powershell, certificate

i do have a variable which contains a base64 string (a certificate).I want to convert this to an cryptoggraphic object via powershell, like this:

```
$cert_object = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(".\tmp.txt")
```

But i´m unable to create this object without this hack because i did not find a way to directly pipe the string to the crypto object...

```
$cert.value | Out-File -FilePath ".\tmp.txt"
#This parses the base64 and createa a certificate object
$cert_object = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(".\tmp.txt")
#Remove the uglyness
Remove-Item -Path ".\tmp.txt"
```

Does anyone now a solution without touching disk?

Comment: if the b64 string is in `$cert.Value` then you can simply convert it from b64 and then use those bytes to target the `new([byte[]] $rawData)` ctor

Comment: Thank you, can you maybe give a example with the whole command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$cert.value` contains the Base64 string you could convert it from Base64 and use those bytes to target the [`X509Certificate2(Byte[])` Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate2-ctor(system-byte())):

```bash
[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new(
    [Convert]::FromBase64String($cert.value)
)
```

As an example using a Cert in `My`:

```bash
$bytes = (Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Select-Object -First 1).RawData
$cert  = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new(
    [Convert]::FromBase64String($cert)
)
```